# FlashBuilder - Errors that only I get and no one else does

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

I work for a company that develops both Mobile (C# with Unity) and Facebook (AS3 with Flashbuilder) apps.  To my knowledge, everyone is using the same versions of the IDEs and SDKs associated.  I have now encountered 2 separate errors that only I get and nobody else (a team of about 30) get.

First error, we had couple of functions in our C# code that were translated to AS3.  C# allows overloaded functions, while AS3 does not, so when we ported to AS3, we had to pick one of the following:

```
Object.SetMidposition(float x, float y);
Object.SetMidposition(Point point);
```

got translated into AS3 as:

```
Object.SetMidposition(x:Number, y:Number)
```

However, there were a couple of spots in our code base where the translation missed converting the Point to an x,y pair, so we had a call where it was trying to Object.SetMidposition(Point) when it was looking for (x,y).  This should have errored out for everyone, but for some reason only errored out for me.  I have no idea why it only broke for me, and no one else.

Second error, a developer made an if statement with an XOR comparison:

```
if(boolA ^ boolB)
{
 //Do stuff
}
```

I looked up the ^ operator, and it is indeed an XOR, and this should work.  And it does! For everyone except me.  In my environment, I get an error at this line saying that I cannot implicitly convert booleans to Numbers.  I have no idea why it thinks I am trying to convert booleans to Numbers, or why I am the only one who is having this issue.

So an error that should have broke everyone, but only broke me, and another error that should not break anyone, but breaks me.

What gives?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you build? How do the others build?

Comment: I guess I do not understand your question.  Project -> Clean, or just Run Debug, which builds and launches the app.  To my knowledge there is only a couple of ways to 'Build' your project.

Comment: "...where the translation missed converting..." your code is not strong typed? Try to make it so, so you can't compile until complete "translation".

Comment: ...the bug was changes status to RESOLVED WORKSFORME...

Comment: @Vesper, what **exactly** works for you? There are two issues and no code to replicate. Infact I suspect the problem lies in the "not shown" code...

Comment: @DSalis, reagrding `SetMidposition` only you can answer that, did you update/overwrite all code like how others updated? Couldn't one of your colleagues "set it up" for you?... Regarding the `if(boolA ^ boolB)` leading to error about numbers... what happens when you deug using `trace("class type is : " + getQualifiedClassName(myVar) );` where `myVar` is either `boolA` or `boolB`, do you get "Boolean" returned as type?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In FB, under Project Properties > Flex Compiler, if "Enable strict type checking" and "Enable warnings" are checked I get the "implicit coercion.." error with the XOR comparison. Unchecking those suppresses the error. My preference is to enable the type checking and warnings – but I have a low tolerance for silly bugs

I couldn't follow the other issue you mention.

---

[image]

---

```
var boolA:Boolean = true;
var boolB:Boolean = false;

if(boolA ^ boolB)
{
    trace("bingo");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! My checkbox for that setting wasn't in the same place as yours, but once I found it, it removed the error.  I'd be willing to bet that this and the other issue are related.  The other issue was that we had code that was trying to send in a Point as a parameter to a function that required 2 Numbers (x,y), and it was only breaking for me when it should have been breaking for everyone.  I'd bet type checking is why it broke it for me and no one else.